# Can I display asciidoc document in github?

Tags: github, asciidoc

Am I able to display an asciidoc file on github in the same way that I can currently view a markdown file? According to this blog [entry](http://asciidoctor.org/news/2013/01/30/asciidoc-returns-to-github/), I should be able to do this:

> If you’re interested in using AsciiDoc, head over to GitHub and create a new file in one of your repositories or gists using the file extension .asciidoc or .adoc.

However I tried to do this and it did not work. Can anyone tell me how to get an asciidoc document to display the nicely formatted text on Github?

Here is a document that I was trying to test with Asciidoc.
https://github.com/00krishna/proj_blog/blob/master/test.adoc

Comment: Do you have the URL for a document that doesn't display correctly?

Comment: Hey @KeithThompson , I just added a link to a test file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your file isn't syntactically valid (or rather the line is treated as plain text).

Your original file:

```
==This is a test
this is a test of using asciidoc
```

There's no space after the `==`; I believe it's required.

A modified version that displays correctly:

```
== This is a test
this is a test of using asciidoc
```

See `test.adoc` and `test2.adoc` in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/4887c570586ff0c5e045).

The syntax for this feature, "One line titles", is documented in the [Asciidoc user guide](http://asciidoc.org/userguide.html#_document_structure), [section 11.2](http://asciidoc.org/userguide.html#X46).

Comment: Haha, as simple as that eh. That is great. Thanks for the tips. I got it to work on github as well.

Comment: Just to clarify. File with extension `.adoc` won't appear in Github Wiki, only `.asciidoc` works there. But when you have `.adoc` file in your repo and open it from `code browser`  it will be rendered fine.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the accepted answer, Github (or at least the Wiki portion of Github) only accepts the `.asciidoc` suffix. `.adoc` and `.ad` don't seem to work.  I only came upon this because I tried to manually change the pages in the wiki from `.md` to `.ad` and they wouldn't render, so check this if your problem persists.

Comment: Perhaps `.ad` doesn't work, but `.adoc` does, at least for the examples in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902890/827263).